# Bootstrap popover dismiss function not working in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

There is two buttons "Button 1" for display popover and "Button 2" for an external link. Added some customized jquery for "Button 1" to **dismiss popover when we tap anywhere on the body**, but its **not working on iPhone** (it dismiss only when tap on the same button in iphone)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").tooltip({
            selector: "a[data-toggle='tooltip']",
            container: "body"
        })
                .popover({
                    selector: "a[data-toggle='popover']",
                    container: "body",
                    html: true
                });
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('a[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
            if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
                    $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
                    $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#000;padding-top:50px;"> 
  <a data-placement="top" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title=""> Button1 </a> 
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Button2</a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"body" tag not working on iphone, i have added a class to body. Now its working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").tooltip({
            selector: "a[data-toggle='tooltip']",
            container: "body"
        })
                .popover({
                    selector: "a[data-toggle='popover']",
                    container: "body",
                    html: true
                });
    });

    $('.bodyClass').on('click', function (e) {
        $('a[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
            if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
                    $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
                    $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
    });
```